# My toolbar doesn't show up in CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, cardview

I want to make a CardView recycler adapter to display 2 things(like first image).i have 2 xml layouts one with the toolbar and the other with the CardView.The problem is that the CardView is being displayed at the beginning of the screen and no toolbar is been displayed (only the arrow but still...).

[image: The way i want it]

This is what I get:

[image: The way i have it]

**Here is my first xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constr"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsAct.SettingsActiv">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarSettings"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/todayToolbarSettingsBtn"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbarSettings"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbarSettings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/settingsText"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbarSettings" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is my second xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height=".5dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**And here is my main activity**

```
class SettingsActiv : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)


        val constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constr) as ConstraintLayout
        val recyclerView =  RecyclerView(this)
        val series = ArrayList<SeriesModel>()
        series.add(SeriesModel("Unit of length","Meter"))
        series.add(SeriesModel("Unit of temperature","Celcius"))
        val adapter = MyAdapter(series)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        constraintLayout.addView(recyclerView)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the constraint layout with a LinearLayout, set its orientation to vertical and use this code to add the recyclerview:

```
val linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.constr) as LinearLayout
recyclerView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
linearLayout.addView(recyclerView, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbarSettings))
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Still the same problem.The second xml with the card view is on top(like my second image)

Comment: What style are you using?

Comment: what do you mean?(sorry i'm new)

Comment: Oh. In your styles.xml you can set your theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and then your Toolbar will be effective by default.

Comment: i have it like this!i put my cardview a transparent color and i can see that it's behind my cardview.i want my cardview to be exactly at the bottom of my toolbar.Check my photo [link](https://ibb.co/itOpoK)